# What does it mean to "and find the coordinates of X with respect to A, B."?

Tags: linear-algebra

thanks for using your time on this.

I am studying linear algebra through the Serge Lang book, and i found this exercise:

"Express the given vector X as a linear combination of the given vectors A, B,
and find the coordinates of X with respect to A, B."

I know what writing a vector as a linear combination of 2 others means and I know how to do that, although I don't know exactly what he means by "find the coordinates of X **with respect to A, B**."

By the way, I also know how to write the coordinates of a vector in an especific base, but I am pretty sure A or B is not a base, they are just different two-dimentional vectors.

Heres an exemple from the book:
$X = (1, 0), A = (1, 1), B = (0, 1)$

Can you show me what writting the coordinates of X with respect to A, B is like?

Comment: It means the scalars used for the linear combination. The coordinates of $X$ wrt $A,B$ would be $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ such that $X=\lambda_1 A+\lambda_2 B$; just like how a point with coordinates $(x,y)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ are the coordinates wrt the canonical basis vectors $\{(1,0),(1,0)\}$

Comment: $X = 1 \cdot A + (-1) \cdot B$, so the coordinates of $X$ with respect to $A, B$ are $(1, -1)$. The vectors $A, B$ do form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, because they are linearly independent.

Comment: thank you very much. I got confused with this language